# How can I enable auth only for external clients in Spring for a microservices project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, microservices

I'm working on a project where I am using microservices to handle various portions of my business logic. My current implementation uses JWT tokens to authenticate requests. For performance reasons, I need intermodule requests to skip the token generation or authentication step and always be allowed.

One approach I thought of was configuring my project modules to use a token with an "infinite" expiry so to speak. Is this an appropriate approach or is there a better way to achieve what I want.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no, it's probably a big security issue I would say... instead, look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html section 15.2 and disable Auth for specific net (in this case, the network you are using for your microservices)

Comment: Thanks for linking that. I'll take a look at whitelisting specific IPs. Could you explain why my initial thought could be a security issue? Any particular scenarios or conditions under which that could be problematic?

Comment: well you can probably do that, and it would became a API token (a token with no expire date...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final approach that ended up working for me was a service which creates a refreshed JWT token at an interval that's a few seconds shorter than the token expiry.

Then a RestInterceptor adds this Bearer token to all requests that are for intermodule communication (which is detected by matching hostnames).

All of this is contained in a security JAR which is used in each module. This also has the advantage of allowing every module to have it's own authentication endpoint (the private key is shared) so even if one service is somehow down, the other services can still be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concern with the authentication and not authorization, I mean, if you want to ensure that a certain microservice can only be called by specific microservices but you don't care what operations or endpoints are called on this service, you can use mutual-tls.

With this mechanism in addition to the server, the client in an HTTP connection must authenticate itself using a certificate. By doing so both client and server trust the other part and the communication can be authenticated.

Doing it this way you can forget about tokens, and its expiry time

Comment: Yes I'm only looking for authorization at the moment. Thanks! I'll look into this approach